# OneToMany relation: updating the Many side makes it disapper from the One side?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, associations

So I got these two classes in a Spring Boot/Hibernate project, Doctor:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Doctor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;



    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "doctor")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Patient> patients;
}
```

And the Patient:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Patient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @Range(min=1, max=150)
    private int age;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "doctor_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Doctor doctor;

    @OneToOne
    private Receipt receipt;
}
```

They got the following columns generated :

Doctor : id, name

Patient: id, age,name, doctor_id,receipt_id (dont worry about the receipt part)

The problem is that by updating a Patient (with a regular JPARepository save() method) I can get a updated Patient with findall/findbyId but it disappears from the Doctor's list.

I figure my associations annotations are the problem, any idea how would it work?

!Edit!

here is the Controller for Patient:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/patient")

public class PatientController {

private  PatientService patientService;

public PatientController(PatientService patientService) {
    this.patientService = patientService;
}

@GetMapping
public List<Patient> getAllPatients() {
    return patientService.getAllPatients();
}

@GetMapping ("/{id}")

public Patient getPatientById(@PathVariable Long id){
    return patientService.getPatientById(id);
}

@DeleteMapping("/{id}")

public void deletePatientById(@PathVariable Long id) {
    patientService.deletePatientById(id);
}


@PostMapping

public void savePatient(@RequestBody Patient patient) {
    patientService.save(patient);
}



@PutMapping("/{id}")
public void updatePatientById(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Patient patient) {
    patient.setId(id);
    patientService.save(patient);

}
```

}

The save in the service layer is just the regular JPARepository save method.

Comment: could you draft a sample code that does not work? there can be a few options

Comment: What is in that Patient instance when you call save on it? Specifically the doctor reference. If it is null, that will explain your issue, as you are setting the relationship in the database to nullI suspect your JsonBackReference/JsonManagedReference are backwards to what you have in JPA; the relationship is controlled by the Patient side, so it is the one that always needs a doctor. If you aren't passing full instances around, you'll need to find a way to read in the existing instance and merge only the properties you are passing around (like the name, age) and leave the others as is.

Comment: I only tried saving the "age" variable, using my put method in Postman (localhost:8080/patient/1 where 1 is the id of a Patient), but it seems like its only creating a new Patient with id1 age whatever, and every other field is null (not updating)

All I can think about every  time I save a Patient somehow I should get the Doctor who has it and manually add to its list again.

Gonna edit my question and add the method in Controller too.